# Finding parabola (arc) that passes through two points with a given height gain

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given that I have two points `(3, 2)` and `(6, 4)` as well as a determined desired height gain (say perhaps of 2). How can I construct the equation for a parabola that passes these two points?

My goal is to then take the explicit derivative at *point 1* and launch an item at that velocity (at that angle which I'm not sure how I'll get) in order to have it follow the path of the parabola.

Diagram (excuse my inability to use Demos efficiently):
[image]

Comment: Since it looks like you’ve got a downward force acting on the object, presumably you also want this parabola to have its axis parallel to the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [amd's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604084/finding-parabola-arc-that-passes-through-two-points-with-a-given-height-gain/3604093#comment7408550_3604084), with the parabola having an [axis of symmetry parallel to the $y$ axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#In_a_Cartesian_coordinate_system), we have that

> ... if the vertex is $V = (v_1, v_2)$, the focus $F = (v_1, v_2 + f)$ and the directrix $y = v_2 - f$, one obtains the equation $$y = \frac{1}{4f}(x - v_1)^2 + v_2$$

For simpler algebra, let $a = \frac{1}{4f}$ and $b = v_1$. If we have $g$ be the amount you wish to gain on point $2$, i.e., $(6,4)$, then $v_2 = 4 + g$. Thus, the parabola equation can then be written as

$$y = a(x - b)^2 + (4 + g) \implies y = ax^2 - 2abx + ab^2 + (4 + g) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Plugging in your $2$ points gives $2$ equations in $2$ unknowns which we can then solve for $a$ and $b$.

In particular, for $(3, 2)$ with your example, we get

$$2 = 9a - 6ab + ab^2 + (4 + g) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

and, for $(6, 4)$, we have

$$4 = 36a - 12ab + ab^2 + (4 + g) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Next, \eqref{eq3A} minus \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$2 = 27a - 6ab = a(27 - 6b) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Multiply both sides of \eqref{eq2A} by $27 - 6b$ and use \eqref{eq4A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2(27 - 6b) & = 9(2) - 6(2)b + (2)b^2 + (4 + g)(27 - 6b) \\
54 - 12b & = 18 - 12b + 2b^2 + 108 - 24b + 27g - 6gb \\
0 & = 2b^2 + (-24 - 6g)b + (72 + 27g)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This is now a quadratic equation you can solve for $b$ (making sure, if you want the maximum to be between the $2$ points, that the root you choose is such that $3 \lt b \lt 6$), then use this to determine $a$ in \eqref{eq4A} (and ensure that $a \lt 0$ so the parabola vertex is a maximum, rather than a minimum).

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to convert it to equation form so I can use it in code as I need it to take in multiple sets of unknown points

Comment: Could there be a simpler (more algebra friendly) way to do this if I were to assume one point to me (0,0) the other to be just the difference between the two?

Comment: @CamJ If one of the points is $(0,0)$, then you would get from my ($1$), assuming more generally the second point's $y$ co-ordinate is $y_2$ instead of $4$, $0 = 0 + ab^2 + (y_2 + g) \implies ab^2 = -y_2 - g$. Since $0 \lt b \lt y_2$, you should then get $a = -\frac{y_2 + g}{b^2}$. Also, for you second point, say it's $(x_2,y_2)$, you would get $y_2 = ax_2^2 - 2abx_2 + 0$, so you can substitute for $a$ and solve for $b$ here. I'll leave it to you to do the rest.

Comment: how did you get 25 from 36-9?

Comment: @Robotex Thanks for pointing out that typo. I also have now noticed I had several other typos and mistakes, which I've now all fixed. If you notice any other issues, please let me know.

Comment: Can you explain the equation (1)? How did you get it?

Comment: @Robotex I've updated my answer to explain that $(1)$ comes from a standard form 
of equation for parabolas with axes parallel to the $y$-axis.